# Cannot access Google Play store on Bluestacks

Tags: google-play-store, bluestacks

Got the dreaded "There was a problem communicating with Google servers, try again later" error. This all started with notifications stating my account could not Sync with any of my apps. Seen many posts with possible solutions ...
1.Removed the account, then tried to re-add it and got the above message. Tried to add other accounts ... same thing.
[image: bluestacks error]
 [image: BoomBeach cannot buy diamonds]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried beaming an app to bluestacks using appcast?